# Convert null values to empty array in Spark DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-1.5

I have a Spark data frame where one column is an array of integers. The column is nullable because it is coming from a left outer join. I want to convert all null values to an empty array so I don't have to deal with nulls later.

I thought I could do it like so:

```
val myCol = df("myCol")
df.withColumn( "myCol", when(myCol.isNull, Array[Int]()).otherwise(myCol) )
```

However, this results in the following exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class [I [I@5ed25612
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$.apply(literals.scala:49)
at org.apache.spark.sql.functions$.lit(functions.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.sql.functions$.when(functions.scala:778)
```

Apparently array types are not supported by the `when` function. Is there some other easy way to convert the null values?

In case it is relevant, here is the schema for this column:

```
|-- myCol: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: integer (containsNull = false)
```

Comment: Take a look at coalesce sql function https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions033.htm#SQLRF00617

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use an UDF:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf

val array_ = udf(() => Array.empty[Int])
```

combined with `WHEN` or `COALESCE`:

```scala
df.withColumn("myCol", when(myCol.isNull, array_()).otherwise(myCol))
df.withColumn("myCol", coalesce(myCol, array_())).show
```

In the *recent versions* you can use `array` function:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{array, lit}

df.withColumn("myCol", when(myCol.isNull, array().cast("array<integer>")).otherwise(myCol))
df.withColumn("myCol", coalesce(myCol, array().cast("array<integer>"))).show
```

Please note that it will work only if conversion from `string` to the desired type is allowed.

The same thing can be of course done in PySpark as well. For the legacy solutions you can define `udf`

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, IntegerType

def empty_array(t):
    return udf(lambda: [], ArrayType(t()))()

coalesce(myCol, empty_array(IntegerType()))
```

and in the recent versions just use `array`:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import array

coalesce(myCol, array().cast("array<integer>"))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I had actually tried a UDF before but didn't think to actually call `apply` on it (i.e. I was doing `array_` instead of `array_()`).

Comment: @zero323 how would you do this in pyspark?

Comment: @harppu This answers it for pyspark for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57198009/503826

Answer (score 17):

With a slight modification to zero323's approach, I was able to do this without using a udf in Spark 2.3.1.

```
val df = Seq("a" -> Array(1,2,3), "b" -> null, "c" -> Array(7,8,9)).toDF("id","numbers")
df.show
+---+---------+
| id|  numbers|
+---+---------+
|  a|[1, 2, 3]|
|  b|     null|
|  c|[7, 8, 9]|
+---+---------+

val df2 = df.withColumn("numbers", coalesce($"numbers", array()))
df2.show
+---+---------+
| id|  numbers|
+---+---------+
|  a|[1, 2, 3]|
|  b|       []|
|  c|[7, 8, 9]|
+---+---------+
```

Comment: In PySpark you can do the second approach, just do `df2 = df.withColumn("numbers", coalesce(col("numbers"), array()))`

Answer (score 5):

An UDF-free alternative to use when the data type you want your array elements in can not be cast from `StringType` is the following:

```py
import pyspark.sql.types as T
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.withColumn(
    "myCol",
    F.coalesce(
        F.col("myCol"),
        F.from_json(F.lit("[]"), T.ArrayType(T.IntegerType()))
    )
)
```

You can replace `IntegerType()` with whichever data type, also complex ones.