# pyspark 2.2.1: How to fill null value of a column with empty list

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe, df

```
id alias
1  ["jon", "doe"]
2 null
```

I am trying to replace the nulls and use an empty list

```
id alias
1  ["jon", "doe"]
2 []
```

I tried using

`.fillna('alias', '[]')` 
`.fillna('alias', create_list([])`

and answers from [Convert null values to empty array in Spark DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34660867/convert-null-values-to-empty-array-in-spark-dataframe)

but none of them are syntactically correct.

Answer (score 1):

Due to column types are different, you can't use fillna directly. You can use something like below

```
df.show()
+---+----------+
| id|     alias|
+---+----------+
|  1|[jon, doe]|
|  2|      null|
+---+----------+


import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df.select([ F.coalesce(F.col(col[0]), F.array()).alias(col[0]) if col[1].startswith('array') else F.col(col[0]) for col in df.dtypes]).show()
+---+----------+
| id|     alias|
+---+----------+
|  1|[jon, doe]|
|  2|        []|
+---+----------+
```