# DataFrame column (Array type) contains Null values and empty array (len =0). How to convert Null to empty array?

Tags: arrays, pyspark, null

I've Spark DataFrame with a Array column (StringType)

**Sample DataFrame:**

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
  [None],   
  [[]],   
  [['foo']] 
]).toDF("a")
```

**Current Output:**

```
+-----+
|    a|
+-----+
| null|
|   []|
|[foo]|
+-----+
```

**Desired Output:**

```
+-----+
|    a|
+-----+
|   []|
|   []|
|[foo]|
+-----+
```

I need to convert the Null values to an empty Array to concat with another array column.

Already tried this, but it's not working

```
df.withColumn("a",F.coalesce(F.col("a"),F.from_json(F.lit("[]"), T.ArrayType(T.StringType()))))
```

[Convert null values to empty array in Spark DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34660867/convert-null-values-to-empty-array-in-spark-dataframe)

Comment: Great question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `array` function.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
  [None],   
  [[]],   
  [['foo']] 
]).toDF("a")

import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.withColumn('a', F.coalesce(F.col('a'), F.array(F.lit(None)))).show(10, False)
+-----+
|a    |
+-----+
|[]   |
|[]   |
|[foo]|
+-----+
```

---

The result is now array(string), so there is no null value. Please check the results.

```
temp = spark.sql("SELECT a FROM table WHERE a is NULL")
temp.show(10, False)
temp = spark.sql("SELECT a FROM table WHERE a = array(NULL)")
temp.show(10, False)
temp = spark.sql("SELECT a FROM table")
temp.show(10, False)


+---+
|a  |
+---+
+---+

+---+
|a  |
+---+
|[] |
+---+

+-----+
|a    |
+-----+
|[]   |
|[]   |
|[foo]|
+-----+
```

Comment: I still have Null values. Column is `ArrayType(StringType)` Does that make sense?

Comment: what version of spark, python?

Comment: Spark 3 and Python 3.6

Comment: Even my code is for spark 3.0.0 and python 3.8.5. I think the spark version is the matter, so it should work. I have added my full code.

Comment: It's a bit weird. If I query in Superset with a `WHERE <col> IS NULL` then I don't have any Null values for any column. When I query without the `WHERE` clause (with the respective columns) I see Null values.

Comment: schema:   
`col_a: array (nullable = false)
   --element: string (containsNull = true)`   

`col_b: array (nullable = false)
   --element: string (containsNull = true)`   

`col_c: array (nullable = false)
   --element: string (containsNull = true)`

Comment: I've 3 columns to concatenate; `col_a` result  is same as your example. For `col_b `and `col_c `the result for query 2 is equal to query 1. `col_aa` is converted from `varchar` to `Array(String)` and `col_b`& `col_c` were already of the type `Array(String)` . After the concatenate the new column is sometimes `Null` while there's a value in one of the cols.

Comment: I need the duplicates and i've 3 columns. It's the input for a UDF.

Comment: Can you update your question with reproducible data? I cannot imagine how it happen.

Comment: I checked the new column the same as `col_a`..etc. and there are no hits for query 1. I'll try to export the results to csv to check

Comment: Results are not displayed properly (Presto/Superset) . After export and verification of the CSV everything appears to be correct. Thank you very much for your patience and help !!